# Image inside circle not properly centered

Tags: html, css, position

I wonder why my code not works! I want to center my images on my two circle shape but currently I do not understand why they are not centered despite having set everything right, in my opinion, I hope someone can help me, thanks. This is my code!
with width and height 100% there is no problems, but I would like to leave some space on the sides of the internal images

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  overflow: auto;
}
button, a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5% 5%;
}
.header-left, .header-right {
  color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.social {
  color: var(--main-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.social-button {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: #1F1C2E;   /* colore icona */
  border: 2px solid #1F1C2E;  /* colore bordo */
  padding: 0;
}


#kofi_img, #github_img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2%;
}

.header span, a, button {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <span id="name" class="name menu">mySite</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <div class="social">
        <a id="github" class="social-button menu" target="_blank" href="https://github.com">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZfPtzn/Git-Hub-Mark-64px.png" alt="GitHub" height="84%" width="84%">
        </a>
        <a id="kofi" class="social-button menu" target="_blank" href="https://ko-fi.com">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PCyyCY8/kofi.png" alt="kofi" height="84%" width="84%"></img>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Ive changed height and width to 50% and it still looks centered https://jsfiddle.net/azhxbcv8/1/ 
84% in your example is centered too btw.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a small discrepancy of white space between edges of images icons and borders.

Maybe try removing width and height percentages from your HTML and using CSS to apply these sizes, instead.

This stretched the images to fit more centered.

Your icons are collapsing when the screen resizes, as well. Adding a containing div or other semantic tag will keep this from occurring.

Lastly, your #kofi_img and #github_img selectors aren't doing what you may think.

By removing the underscores from each, you will indeed be selecting the images within those anchors!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
</head>

<body>
      <div class="social">
        <div class="icon_container">
          <a id="github" class="social-button menu" target="_blank" href="https://github.com">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZfPtzn/Git-Hub-Mark-64px.png" alt="GitHub">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="icon_container">
          <a id="github" class="social-button menu" target="_blank" href="https://github.com">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZfPtzn/Git-Hub-Mark-64px.png" alt="GitHub">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

```
.social {
  color: var(--main-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon_container {
  background-color: coral;
}

.social-button {
  background-color: teal;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: #1F1C2E;   /* colore icona */
  border: 2px solid #1F1C2E;  /* colore bordo */
  padding: 0;
}

#kofi img, #github img {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/permalik/0csfnu6L/32/

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the Github image you can see that it is not itself absolutely centered - you are bound to get a larger gap at the bottom of the circle than at the top. Here is a blown up screen shot:

[image]

I can't see the same problem with the kofi logo